# Add digits and count letters of a string (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

As part of an assignment, I must write a program that gets a string from the user, and prints out the number of letters in that string, as well as the sum of the digits in that string. So for example, if I were to type in `abc123` as my string, the program should tell me that there are 3 letters and the sum of the digits is `6`(3+2+1). The program must use corecursive functions (i.e. the functions call each other). My code so far is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Function prototypes
void countAlph(char str[], int, int);
void sumDigits(char str[], int, int);

int main(void)
{
    //Create an array that can hold 25 characters
    char anStr[25];
    int inputSize;

    //Get string from user
    printf("Enter an alphanumeric string:\n");
    scanf("%s", anStr);

    //Get size (# of elements in the array)
    inputSize = strlen(anStr);

    //Function call
    countAlph(anStr, inputSize, 0); //pass the string, size of the string, and 0 (first index position)
}

//function that counts # of letters
void countAlph(char str[], int size, int currentIndex)
{
    //use ASCII codes!

    int alphaCount = 0, i;

    if(currentIndex < size)
    {
        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            if((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) || (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)) //if element is a letter
            {
                alphaCount++; //increase # of letters by 1
            }
            else if(str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57) //if element is NOT a letter
            {
                sumDigits(str, size, i); //go to the sumDigits function
            }
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d letters in this string\n", alphaCount);
}

//function that adds all the digits together
void sumDigits(char str[], int size, int currentIndex)
{
    //use ASCII codes!

    int sum = 0, i;

    if(currentIndex < size)
    {
        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57) //if element is a digit
            {
                //I found the line of code below online after searching how to convert from ASCII to int
                str[i] = str[i] - '0'; //this converts the ascii value of the element to the decimal value
                sum = sum + str[i]; //add that digit to the running sum
            }
            else if((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) || (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)) //if element is NOT a number
            {
                countAlph(str, size, i); //go to the countAlph function
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of the digits of this string is %d\n", sum);
}
```

My program works correctly if my string contains ONLY numbers or ONLY letters. But if I enter an alphanumeric string such as `"abc123"` I get a segmentation fault. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I assume the issue is related to my loop logic, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your two functions call each other. Each one passes `currentIndex` to the other, but each ignores the `currentIndex` it gets from the other and starts over from `i = 0`.

So if you give it a string that has a transitions from letters to numerals (e.g. "g3") the two functions call each other until they overload the call stack.

One solution: have the functions *use* `currentIndex`.

Another solution: handle letters and numerals in one function.

Comment: I can't reproduce the OP's problem.

Comment: @iharob: I just corrected an error in my answer, but the problem is definitely there. When I try "g3", `countAlph` calls `sumDigits`, which calls `countAlph`, which calls `sumDigits`, and so on. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Yes indeed. I just tested `g3` and reproduced the Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _use_ `currentIndex`. Use it in what way? I suppose it should be incremented somewhere, so that if the element at that index is NOT a letter, it moves to the next index position and goes to the sumDigits function. I definitely understand the error in logic that you pointed out though.

Comment: I have since initialized `i` to `currentIndex` (instead of initializing it to 0). In some sense, this resolved the issue in that the program can now read alphanumeric strings. However, it seems that the counts reset when there is a transition from letter to number, and the `printf` statements print multiple times for alphanumeric strings.

Comment: @louiedro: Each function has a `printf` statement, and the functions call each other; if you're surprised that there are multiple lines of output, then you still fundamentally misunderstand what this code is doing. The counts reset at `alphaCount = 0` and `sum = 0`, but more fundamentally two calls to the same function are independent-- they generally don't know about each other and each has it's own version of the variables like `alphaCount` and `sum`.